# On Android, impossible to use DDMS method profiling on emulators or devices

Tags: android, methods, sdk, profiling, ddms

I have a problem when I try to use method profiling on my Windows 7 64 bits platform. When I do so, this kills a bunch process on any emulator or real device I use, including the one I want to profile. Or nothing happens at all (see trace below)

Is that due to a recent version of the Android SDK?

I have been able to use method profiling on a Linux 32 bits platform.

Any clue?

Here is a trace I have on an Nexus S (api level 10) like emulator.

```
08-15 08:11:04.847: D/dalvikvm(409): +++ active profiler count now 1
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409): TRACE STARTED: '[DDMS]' 1048576KB
08-15 08:11:04.847: D/dalvikvm(409): +++ active profiler count now 0
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409): Exception thrown by dispatcher for 0x4d505353
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409): Ljava/lang/InternalError;: buffer alloc failed
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409):    at dalvik.system.VMDebug.startMethodTracingNative(Native Method)
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409):    at dalvik.system.VMDebug.startMethodTracingDdms(VMDebug.java:207)
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409):    at android.os.Debug.startMethodTracingDdms(Debug.java:481)
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409):    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPSS(DdmHandleProfiling.java:148)
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409):    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:81)
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409):    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
08-15 08:11:04.847: I/dalvikvm(409):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. The point was that in the Android/DDMS options, the "Method Profiler buffer size" was set to 1024. I changed it to 8192 and now everything is as smooth as I want.

Hope this helps.